# CPLEX solving models and detecting infeasibility

Tags: python, optimization, cplex, docplex

I would like to solve a given problem using CPLEX. If the problem is infeasible I would like to detect it as soon as possible and use that information to solve some other problem. I wrote the following code, but I am not sure if it is the best way to do it.

```
try:
    model.solve()
    if model.solution_value>best_solution_value:
         best_solution_value=model.solution_value
except:
    best_solution_value=best_solution_value
```

The problem cannot be unbounded, and in most cases the main reason the solver wouldn't work be the infeasibilty.

Would this be the most efficient way to do it? Is there any other better ways to do it?

Comment: any ideas about the problem?

Comment: What is the meaning of `best_solution_value=best_solution_value`?

Comment: it is the incumbent optimal solution

Comment: Is it ever useful to write something like `x=x`?

Comment: Oh yeah, I just wrote it as I have to write something to except part. In the actual code it is different of course.

Answer (score 0):

Solving an infeasible problem does not raise ay exception: it returns `None`.
So testing for feasibility should only check the return value of `solve()`.

However, proving a problem to be infeasible may take a long time, especially for large MIP problems. You may consider setting a time limit for the solve, and check whether a solution is found in this time frame. But this will not *prove* that your problem has no solution.